# Display multiple identical polygons (with different attributes) on map

Tags: qgis, polygon, visualisation, overlapping-features

I need to create maps of multiple species in a certain area. However sometimes multiple species occurr in the exact same area. This results in two identical polygons on top of each other. Many of these polygons are for example a UTM1 square of 1 by 1 km.

When making a map I should be able to make it clear that there are multiple species that occur in that polygon. However through the syles menu I can only make the colors blend while ideally when 3 polygons are on top of each other I should get some sort of pie diagramm or a checkerboard pattern containing the colors of both species.

Does anyone know a plugin or elegant way to do this? So far I have only found stuff like the v.clean option, but I do not want to remove the overlapping polygons, quite the opposite, I want to visualise the overlapping polygons as well as the non-overlapping ones with a clear legend.

Comment: What is the maximum amount of different species you have in one region?

Comment: I'd say it will be around 4 but the total amount of squares for which I have more than one is quite high so a manual job is not really an option.

Answer (score 1):

I have created 3 polygons called Deer Lions Bears, and used the Tranparency slider on the colour.
[image]

the transparent colours show which polygons overlap

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just adding own layers for regions where multiple species occur? For example, if you have the species A which is visualized green, and the species B which is visualized red, just make the regions where both of them occur blue. Might be a bit too simplistic, but it works in my mind.